# MVC - Add / Remove a style when the user arrives on, or leaves, the home page

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I have an MVC app, with a _Layout.cshtml page that looks as follows (only showing the relevant part):

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container" style="background-image: url(/Images/HeaderBar.png); background-size: cover;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
```

When the user leaves the home page, I want the style you see in the `div` to be present. However, when the user arrives on the home page, I want that style removed. Is there a clean and simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `_Layout.cshtml` you can check the `ViewContext.RouteData["action"]` or `ViewContext.RouteData["controller"]` or `ViewContext.Controller.GetType()` values and conditionally do something.

For example:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container" id="sidebar" style="@(ViewContext.Controller.GetType() == typeof (HomeController) ? "background-image: url(/Images/HeaderBar.png); background-size: cover;" : "")">
    <p> some stuff here</p>
</div>
```

I would additionally recommend using a class to do this instead of an inline style.

Comment: Excellent!! Works great.